# Shear Tool after Other Effect -> Expand Appearance

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-effects, appearance

I want to clarify a small issue with Shear Tool, because I feel there is a common rule I miss.

I created a rectangle and applied Rounded Effect. At this stage I did not expanded appearance.

Next, I applied Shear Tool as you can see on the picture: you can see the bounds of the applied shear tool, however there are no real shape changes - if the object deselected it looks like regular rounded rectangle. If I apply Expand Appearance I get the same rounded rectangle.

What is the general rule that I miss?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Effect > Stylize > Round Corners` rather than `Effect > Convert to Shape > Rounded Rectangle`.

By using the Convert To Shape effect, you are asking the shape, no matter what it is, to be converted to a rounded rectangle. That's literally what the menu reads *convert to shape*.

Using the Round Corners effect will allow you to round corners on any shape.

Answer (score -1):

You need to expand appearance before using the shear tool..

Comment: not true, as explained in the other answer